# how can I connect Postgres in estuary?

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating DynamoDB to Postgres DB by using estuary platform.

I set the source **MATERIALIZATION** as a DynamoDB. and I am gonna set the destination **MATERIALIZATION** as Postgres.

but it doesn't work well. after setting the endpoint and publish, error below:

address: localhost:5432

user: postgres

database: postgres

> panic: failed to connect to `host=localhost user=postgres-dev database=dev`: dial error (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address)

Comment: What happens if you change "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a co-founder of Estuary and can help.

Currently it functions as a SaaS product and requires that connections have an internet address.  If you are trying to connect to localhost, your best bet is to use SSH tunneling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).